# Solutions to the Laplace Equation $\Delta u =0$, where $u= \log p$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Find all real solutions to the two dimensional Laplace equation $U_{xx} + U_{yy} =0$ of the form $u=\log p(x,y)$, where $p$ is a quadratic polynomial.

Solution:

Let $p(x,y) = Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D$ be a quadratic polynomial such that $A, B \not= 0$. Then

$$U_{x} = \frac{2Ax + Cy}{\ln(10)(Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D},$$

$$U_{xx} = \frac{2A ln(10)(Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D) - \ln(10)(2Ax + Cy)^2}{\ln(10) (Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D)^2},$$

$$U_{y} =  \frac{2By + Cx}{\ln(10)(Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D)},$$

$$U_{yy} = \frac{2B \ln(10)(Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D) - \ln(10)(2By + Cx)^2}{\ln(10) (Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D)^2}.$$

This implies

$$U_{xx} + U_{yy} = \frac{2A \ln(10)(Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D) - \ln(10)(2Ax + Cy)^2}{\ln(10) (Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D)^2} + \frac{2B \ln(10)(Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D) - \ln(10)(2By + Cx)^2}{\ln(10) (Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D)^2} = 0. $$

I feel like I am not doing this right. Is there a simpler way? Thanks. And also how do I find such solutions.

Comment: Just curious: Would that $\log$ really be $\ln$ (that simplify things)

Comment: no it is log no ln. that is why i differentiate the way i did

Comment: By a quadratic polynomial wouldn't it be $Ax^2 + By^2 + Cxy + Ex+ Fy + D$?

Comment: so my polynomial is wrong to begin with

Comment: log is almost certainly meant as the base $e$-logarithm, (not that it makes much difference)

Answer (score 0):

This is an heavy method, but you can continue.
$$U_{xx} + U_{yy} = \frac{2A ln(10)(Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D) - ln(10)(2Ax + Cy)^2}{ln(10) (Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D)^2} + \frac{2B ln(10)(Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D) - ln(10)(2By + Cx)^2}{ln(10) (Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D)^2} = 0$$
After simplification :
$$2A(Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D)-(2Ax + Cy)^2 + 2B(Ax^2 + By^2 +Cxy + D)-(2By + Cx)^2=0$$
It is easy to see that $A=B=1\:;\:C=D=0$ is solution. Hense : $p(x,y)=x^2+y^2$
$$U(x,y)=log(x^2+y^2)$$

A simpler method consists in solving first the PDE :
$$U(x,y)=f(x+iy)+g(x-iy)$$
any functions $f$ and $g$.

In case of $f=g=log$ then $U=log(x+iy)+log(x-iy)$
$$U(x,y)=log(x^2+y^2)$$

Comment: It seems that the OP wishes to find all such solutions, but your answer find only one.

Comment: My answer is an hit to the OP showing that he was not on a wrong way : He wrote : ''so my polynomial is wrong to begin with''.  I show him that he has not to be afraid and could continue.

Comment: But using this polynomial could not (a priori) give you all the solutions, and thus cannot solve the OP's problem as in the title. (So the solution is actually wrong)

Comment: The title cannot include all the requirements of the question. The wording is : '' Find all real solutions ... of the form $u=log p(x,y)$ is a quadratic polynomial ''. It is not asked for solutions which are not on this form. By the way, why don't you post your own answer ?

Comment: I mean, all quadratic polynomials are of the form I wrote in the comment of the question. Your solution cannot even find all solution of that form (apriori). I don't write down the answer as your answer can be fixed easily to include the general case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that is proposed makes use of the wolfram language for symbolic computations.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the following link you can download the notebook to explore all the details:

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2108153